# How to really delete an answer?

Tags: support

I wrote an answer to [Is it OK to buy a refurbished MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/is-it-ok-to-buy-a-refurbished-macbook-pro) , and then after posting it I thought better of it, so deleted it. It added nothing to the question being asked as there were already plenty of answers, and my answer was just really another bit of anecdotal evidence. Also the question was asked 11 years ago and I only noticed after posting.

However nothing in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers indicates how to completely delete the answer. Instead it looks like it will hang around as a private embarrassment in that question (though I note it doesn't appear in my activity).

Is there a way of finally deleting something? If not, so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much for asking this.

Unless there's information that needs to be redacted, having a few deleted questions with a comment noting that you had mis-read the question or feel you want it deleted to allow other answers to shine is appropriate.

There's nothing to be ashamed of in your specific post and really no need to even comment as anyone with the reputation needed to see the deleted post will think anything of a routine or normal and expected deletion of the occasional post. There are two other, far less helpful answers hidden on that same question.

You're doing great and I have dozen and dozens of posts just like yours. Voting up other good answers is the perfect way to ensure quality content is here.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I use the word embarrassment with a certain amount of tongue-in-cheek! Just a reminder to be more careful in future.

Comment: And a pro move is to set a reminder in a year, see if time has given you a better grasp and editing that post, undeleting it. This part of the question / answer lifecycle isn't common to many, but as long as the question itself is good, answers can take a long time to reach a useful state

Comment: My apologies. That was a typo - the sentiment was “ routine or normal and expected deletion of the occasional post” which I’ve fixed with an edit @MartinR